# Официальное и неполное название - определение?

Tags: орфография, прописная-строчная

Мильчин пишет:

> 3.14.2. Неполное название, заменяющее полное
> С прописной буквы пишется первое (или единственное) слово усеченного названия. Напр.:
>
> Государственный литературный музей — Литературный музей.

Тогда как отличить неполное название, заменяющее полное, -- от неофициального, которое пишется со строчной? Памятник Шарлю де Голлю в Москве прозвали швейцаром -- здесь понятно. Но если Генеральная прокуратура Республики Узбекистан - полное название, то генеральная прокуратура - неофициальное или неполное? Редактор требует писать со строчной.

Comment: У Лопатина в § 189: В официальных составных названиях органов власти  _Генеральная прокуратура РФ, Министерство иностранных дел Российской Федерации_ пишется первое слово с прописной. Будет ли Генеральная прокуратура России считаться официальным названием, а министерство иностранных дел - неофициальным?

Answer (score 1):

Вообще-то есть вполне четкое определение.
~1. Официальное название - то, что прописано в уставе предприятия или учреждения (или его аналоге для зарубежных фирм). Оно обычно длинное, и зачастую в нем путаются даже сотрудники.
*Федеральное государственное образовательное учреждение Высшего профессионального образования "Московский государственный университет Печати имени Ивана Федорова" (примерно)*
Увы, но на практике, особенно для юридических надобностей, заглавная-строчная тут регулируется не правилами, а исключительно прихотью чиновника, забившего в Устав именно такое написание.

~2. Сокращенное название. Тоже прописано в уставе, что-то наподобие "ФГОУ ВПО МГУ Печати", может использоваться во всякого рода бухгалтерских и ведомственных документах. Тоже лучше всего смотреть устав, а не Лопатина.

~3. Всё остальное можно считать неофициальным названием - и руководствоваться правилами уже без оглядки на бюрократа.

Все приведенные в вопросе примеры, насколько понимаю, попадают в категорию неофициальных. Это ли имел в виду Лопатин, утверждать не буду.

Comment: На "Грамоте. Ру" есть вопрос: Скажите, с какой буквы (прописной или строчной) писать название Л(л)итературный музей, К(к)раеведческий музей, если в полном виде названия звучат так: Нижегородский литературный музей, Пензенский государственный краеведческий музей. 
zhasmin
Ответ справочной службы русского языка
Эти сочетания пишутся строчными буквами.

Как это соотнести с Мильчиным?

Comment: Не могу знать. Вряд ли это мне вопрос, я Мильчина в руках не держал.
Но вообще-то Грамота - источник интересный, но не официальный. Там студентки за грОши ответы ваяют.